# Can I use CSS calc() and vh to calculate time?

Tags: css

I'm trying to set the time of an animation based on how long the distance will be to get a constant speed.

This works:

```
animation: downanim calc((var(--offset)) * 0.0004s);
```

but this does not:

```
animation: upanim calc((var(--offset) - 100vh) * 0.0004s);
```

I also tried this:

```
animation: upanim calc(((var(--offset) - 100vh) / 1vh ) * 0.0004s);
```

Comment: you cannot mix unit with multiplication (only one unit like the first example) and  you cannot divide by a unit

Comment: +1 to previous comment. From [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-type-checking) `At /, check that the right side is <number>. If the left side is <integer>, resolve to <number>. Otherwise, resolve to the type of the left side. `

Comment: @TemaniAfif so no solution to for setting a time based on viewport height?

Comment: @FelipeAls not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Himmators with pure CSS no, there is no way to mix unit like this : it's simple : ask your self what is the relation between 1vh and 1s ? ... is there any relation between weight(kg) and time(s) in real life ?,no ... you need to identify the relation you want first